# Error while sorting list in lambda mode which works fine in if else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Only asc is running and if any other number is added it gives error.
Code is given below

````
    ```y=input("Write 'asc','dec', 'none'")
       converter=lambda x:sorted (x) if y=="asc" else (sorted(x,reverse="True" if y=="dec" else y))
       print (converter (x=[1,2,4,6,10,0, 8, 5]))```
````

Comment: what error do you face?

Comment: The `reverse` parameter should a Boolean, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the reverse argument requires a boolean, not a string (True or False, not "True", because "True" is a string).

from w3school tutorial:

> reverse=True will sort the list descending. Default is reverse=False

So it should be:

```
y=input("Write 'asc','dec', 'none'")
converter=lambda x:sorted(x, reverse=y=="dec") if y != "none" else x
print (converter (x=[1,2,4,6,10,0, 8, 5]))
```

edit:
Alexander's answer assumes that you expect "none" and "asc" to work in the exact same way (sort in ascending order), I assume that you want to return the original list without sorting when "none" is passed, it is not clear which is your expectation according to the question

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong value for the reverse argument in your second sorting function.  The value must be True or False.

I can confirm that this works as expected.

```
y=input("Write 'asc','dec', 'none'")
converter=lambda x:sorted (x) if y=="asc" else (sorted(x,reverse=True if y=="dec" else False))
print (converter (x=[1,2,4,6,10,0, 8, 5]))
```

However your code is doing the same thing as this code which is much easier to understand:

```
print(sorted([1,2,4,6,10,0,8,5], reverse=input()=="desc"))
```

Comment: I hate redundancies in boolean expressions.  `True if input()=="desc" else False` is exactly the same as `input()=="desc"`.

Comment: @MarkRansom  good point